# Page cannot be found only on IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I've got [this webpage](http://accm.com.eg/news/news.html) that's working perfectly on any browser ... except IE9. It flashed for a second then throws what's like a 404 error page cannot be found.

Any idea how can I dig and fix that?

Comment: seems like a security issue with flash. as for digging and fixing it, i'd turn off flash or the script that is calling the swfobject and go from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a script that tries to call this URL : http://accm.com.eg/news/undefined.

IE and other browsers don't handle it in the same way, but the problem isn't the browser. You'll have to find what's wrong with the script ;)

Comment: Seems like that's the issue. Gotta hunt that now